# How to automize numerous programs to run in succession?

Tags: series

I have a series of python files that analyze data in succession. So the first one is an API that streams live data, the second one analyzes the data into another format, the third analyzes it in some way, etc. I want to keep these separate because they can be useful on their own, but I would also like a way to run all of them in succession from the command line with just one command. Is what I'm thinking of a pipeline? Where can I go about learning how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a Pipeline. Here's a useful link: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(Unix)